Xlr output level of Headrush Prime
Sorry if this is a dumb question. Does anyone know what is the XLR output level on headrush prime? I.e amp, mic, line?
I’m planning to use the xlr output to connect my guitar to stagebox (that is then connected to a mixer)

It’s either going to be mic or line level. It wouldn’t be on XLR otherwise.

There is no reason why this should be mic level. Amp level would be only relevant if you were to connect this device to a guitar amp, for which it has an auxiliary output. If you look up the handbook for the device:
https://cdn.inmusicbrands.com/HeadRush/prime/HeadRush%20Prime%20-%20User%20Guide%20-%20v1.0.pdf
you will find a setup diagram on page 5 showing how these XLR main outputs should be connected to FRFR amps. It also states that the TRS amp output should be set to line level for FRFR amps. I think this make quite a clear point that the output level should be line level.

It doesn’t seem to say, but the logical output would be line level since it’s coming from a powered device, but modern mixers have mic/line inputs so it doesn’t really matter in your case. The mixer will accept either one on the same channel input
